# ruby method : If statement inside an if statement

Tags: ruby, syntax, if-statement

i am getting a lot of errors in my program about not having/having too many "end" markers in my program. i have tested this piece of code before and it works but i was just wondering if someone could tell me whether or not i have enough "end"'s in this if statement or too many. Thanks

def hop!(d)

```
if d== 0  
    if @current_location.addpoint(0,1) < @boundary1 
    puts "error"
    elsif if @current_location.addpoint(0,1) > @boundary2
    puts "error2"
    else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(0,1) 
    puts "all good"
    end
    end
elsif d == 1
if @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) < @boundary1 
    puts "error"
    elsif if @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) > @boundary2
    puts "error2"
    else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) 
    puts "all good"
    end
    end
elsif d== 2
if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) <  @boundary1 
    puts "error"
    elsif if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) >  @boundary2
    puts "error2"
    else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(1,0) 
    puts "all good"
    end
    end

else d= 3
if @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) <  @boundary1 
    puts "error"
    elsif if @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) >  @boundary2
    puts "error2"
    else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) 
    puts "all good"
    end
    end

end
```

Comment: If you were following Ruby conventions you wouldn't face this problem.

Comment: You can simplify reading it by assigning your "if-in-if" condition results into variables. Would benefit your code a huge deal!

Answer (score 3):

With a text editor that supports auto-reindentation, your code looks like this:

```
if d== 0  
  if @current_location.addpoint(0,1) < @boundary1 
    puts "error"
  elsif if @current_location.addpoint(0,1) > @boundary2
    puts "error2"
  else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(0,1) 
    puts "all good"
  end
end
elsif d == 1
  if @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) < @boundary1 
    puts "error"
  elsif if @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) > @boundary2
    puts "error2"
  else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) 
    puts "all good"
  end
end
elsif d== 2
  if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) <  @boundary1 
    puts "error"
  elsif if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) >  @boundary2
    puts "error2"
  else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(1,0) 
    puts "all good"
  end
end
else d= 3
  if @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) <  @boundary1 
    puts "error"
  elsif if @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) >  @boundary2
    puts "error2"
  else
    @current_location= @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) 
    puts "all good"
  end
end

end
```

Apart from the incorrect number of `end`s it seems like you're struggling with your `elsif`s, I can't think of any situation where `elsif if [...]` is a good thing to write

Answer (score 3):

It's clear if you indent the code properly. In the following the code is indented properly and the problems with the `end`s and `elsif if` are corrected:

```
def hop!(d)
  if d == 0  
    if @current_location.addpoint(0,1) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(0,1) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(0,1) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  elsif d == 1
    if @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  elsif d == 2
    if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(1,0) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(1,0) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  elsif d == 3
    if @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  end
end
```

Also, in this case using `case` would be more elegant:

```
def hop!(d)
  case d
  when 0
    if @current_location.addpoint(0,1) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(0,1) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(0,1) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  when 1
    if @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  when 2
    if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(1,0) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(1,0) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  when 3
    if @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) < @boundary1 
      puts "error"
    elsif @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) > @boundary2
      puts "error2"
    else
      @current_location = @current_location.addpoint(-1,0) 
      puts "all good"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm.. nothing's clear :) In the OP's code, there are two `end`s after `puts "all good"` but in your indented code, those `end`s are missing. I suppose you fixed that *and* indented the code, but your answer makes it seem that only indentation was the problem. And you fixed the `elsif` problem as well, like @Gareth points out.

Comment: You're right, I also fixed the ends and elsif problem. Didn't mention that at all. Gonna edit the answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
case d
when 1:
  puts "error" and return if @current_location.addpoint(0,1) < @boundary1
  puts "error2" and return if  @current_location.addpoint(0,-1) > @boundary2
  puts "all good"
  break
when 2:
  puts "error" and return if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) < @boundary1 
  puts "error2" and return if @current_location.addpoint(1,0) >  @boundary2
  puts "all good"
  break
when 3:
  ...
```

This should do the trick as well i think.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely better to rewrite with `case`